# What can I do about pocket doors that are blocked by floor tiles?

Tags: doors

I have double pocket doors in my den that I never close.  I was going to clean them today, and when I tried to close them they would not close because of the tile being to high. I had the tile put in about 3 yrs ago, and never even noticed that the tile is to high.  I thought it was because of the grout keeping them from closing, but it's the tile. I was able to get one of them to come out a little, but the other will not budge. Do you have a solution for this without having to take the tile out.

[image: another view]
[image: this is where the door hits the floor]
[image: track]

<sub>Click for full size image</sub>

Comment: How much is it off by?  The doors can lift off the track a little, maybe 1/4 inch (6 mm), and still be fine.

Comment: Pry off all the trim. You should be able to access the hardware, which you can then unscrew the door from to take it out to cut.

Answer (score 2):

That looks tight.

First effort would be to get the adjusters into reach and see if the door can be raised sufficiently.  From the looks of things, that isn't going to be enough.

You could futz around and replace the roller mechanism with a more compact one to gain a little height, but I have found it difficult to obtain compatible parts and very difficult to find anyone who would know where to obtain them.

The surefire solution is to open the walls, take out the doors, cut them to be shorter, reinstall, and then restore the walls.  Easily said, but potentially a lot of work.  However, it is probably easier to get the walls to be restored and looking good than whatever you might do to the flooring.

Answer (score 0):

Most pocket doors have adjustable height settings at the top.  You need to push up on the door while pulling it out - this will get you up to 1/2 inch.  Once it is out you can reach the adjustment nuts at the top of the door.

Comment: The doors are inside the walls. They will not pull out because of the floor tile. One side is out about 6 inches but other Side will not come out at all. It seems that the tile is higher on that one side

Comment: Can you push up on the door at all while it is in the pocket?

Comment: It moves up just a little. Is there a way to send some pictures to show you what I am dealing with?

Comment: @Cindy You can upload images to [imgur](http://imgur.com/), then place a link to them in a comment, or edit them directly into your original question.

Comment: The doors can be adjusted a lot- depends on the mechanism but maybe a half inch.  The door is sliding out which means you might only need 1/8-1/4 inch.  Get it out a little more to see if you can adjust this thing before walls come down.   That is a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the door from the rail (tilt up and out), and pull it out, then trim it. If you really can't get the door out of the frame then you need something to trim the bottom as you open it. A right angle grinding wheel comes to mind. A sawzaw wouldn't have an angle parallel with the floor. A vibrating blade may work for this. My first thought is to cut out the bottom, pull out and cut more, so you can pull this door out and replace it. If you can pull the door out far enough to remove the leading roller, take that first roller off and work from there.

Comment: So your first thought is to do the hardest thing?

Comment: No, read the whole post.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that would be feasible to me is using a "Fein Tool", which is a high-speed vibrating saw tool. You can put in a flush-cut saw blade, lay a piece of 1/2" or so plywood on the floor (to protect the floor AND give a nice cut to the door bottom) then lay the tool flush down and cut off the bottom of the door.

My tool originally cost me $300.00, but Harbor Freight has a knock-off for $40.00. And these have gotten some good reviews... Looks like they give you enough blades to do this task in the new package.

http://www.harborfreight.com/variable-speed-multifunction-power-tool-67537.html

Even if it is used only for this job, it will save you a whole lot of money and time vs. tearing the wall out, as was suggested.

The "difficult part" of this job seems to be that these saw blades are very slender, and so you might have to make slices several times in order to get enough clearance to pull the waste out from the bottom of the door.... So you make a cut(s), then tear out a few inches of the waste, then slide the door closed as far as you can, and cut some more.

One more thing is the blades DO NOT like cutting anything other than wood, so no hardware or nails or stone or tile. If you treat the blade nicely it will last a long time.

You should be able to do this thing in less than an hour. Or so. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

**To allow the door to shut.**

When the doors fully open, screw down some wood that is just over the width of the door to the floor across the opening.

Use an angle grinder to cut the tiles along both edges of your wooden guild.
Remove the wood guild,  and break out the tile between the lines you just cut.

**The door should now have space to shut**.

With the door shut you may be able to remove it so you can cut it down.

If so you can then fill in where you removed the tile with 
a)  Mortar to much the other tile joins
b)  A hard wood strip

If you can’t remove the door, you need to fill in to a level just below the tiles so the door can still close, or use a door saw to cut off the bottom of the door (these can be hired in the UK, I don’t know about the US.