# Any ideas for cutting door bottoms on pocket doors?

Tags: wood, doors, cutting

[What can I do about pocket doors that are blocked by floor tiles?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31461/what-can-i-do-about-pocket-doors-that-are-blocked-by-floor-tiles)

Could you cut out the bottom (1/4-1/2 inch) on a pocket door while it is **still in the frame**?  What tools would you use?  How would you make sure cut is straight?

Comment: You could use a vibrating saw, but the cut, as your next question implies, will be ragged unless you clamp a guide on the door.

Comment: Ideally, you should take the door off and use a power planer to remove small amounts from the bottom.  The one at harbor freight is dirt cheap and could do a small job like this.

Answer (score 2):

Hire a Door Trimming Saw.

[image]

In the UK [HSS](http://www.hss.com/g/3141/Door-Trim-Saw-inc-Blade-.html) stocks them.

Answer (score 1):

Shave the bottom of the pocket door so it clears the tile. You have about an inch and a half of plug inside the hollow core door to trim. Don't shave more than 3/4" off the bottom.  If you can, trim equal amounts off the top and bottom.

Comment: Well why didn't I think of that?

Comment: You did, this was a test question.

Answer (score 1):

The face of hollow core doors can be easily cut with a couple passes  of a utility knife.

Do that first on both sides

Then use a recip saw like a sawzall to cut the whitewood. Leave a 1/16 inch margin. Use blocking on the floor for a level cut.

Answer (score 0):

I'm years late to the party; I just came across this question.
I'd use an undercut saw (a/k/a a jamb saw). An online search will show you images, and you'll see exactly how they work.
They're made specifically for cutting a narrow slice off the underside of baseboards or door jambs, plinth blocks, &c. so that a (higher) floor can run under them.
They're a specialty tool so I don't know about renting. A good flooring installer will likely have one.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this myself.   I have a pocket door that is NOT coming out,  and in order to tile under it I  needed to shave about a quarter inch off the bottom.   I ended up renting a Crain jam saw for like $30 to do most of the damage.   It cut most of it, but in order to get the rest of the door back in the frame I used a kobalt multi use saw to finish the cut.  Its a bit of a pain, but if you want to get it done you'll work through it.   Didn't have to rip out any wall, and my door is cut properly.